# ASCII Table does not format as I want it to be

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord.js, ascii

I'm making a discord bot using MySQL, the database stores some usernames and passwords. I fetch the data from the table in MySQL to format it in an ASCII table. The expected output was to be like the image below. (edited it to look better)

```
.------------------------------------------------.
|       Username       |        Password         |
|----------------------|-------------------------|
|      amonggers       |          no             |
|  no username for u   |          no             |
|  not even this one   |          no             |
|         no           |          no             |
'------------------------------------------------'
```

But the bot forms the table like this.

```
.------------------------------------------------.
|       Username       |        Password         |
|----------------------|-------------------------|
| amonggers            |          no 
 |
| no username for u    |          no
 |
| not even this one    |          no
 |
| no                   |          no             |
'------------------------------------------------'
```

Edit: I also console logged it and the output is a bit better than the discord bot one.

```
.------------------------------------------------.
|       Username       |        Password         |
|----------------------|-------------------------|
 |amonggers            |          no             
 |no username for u    |          no             
 |not even this one    |          no             
|         no           |          no             |
'------------------------------------------------'
```

[![Console Log created][3]][3]
Heres the command code

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("=list")) {
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM rbinfo", (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
            const ascii = require('ascii-table');
            var table = new ascii()
            table.setHeading('Username', 'Password')
            results.forEach(ok => table.addRow(ok.Username, ok.Password))
        });
    }
});
```

Any help at all is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: is that due to line wrapping, like the window is too small?

Comment: I don't think so @vanowm

Comment: but can you highlight the text copy/paste into editor?

Comment: I reckon there are newlines or CR characters in the data. Try changing the query to `SELECT Username, TRIM(TRAILING '\n' FROM Password) AS Password FROM rbinfo` or `SELECT Username, HEX(Password) AS Password FROM rbinfo`.

Comment: Remember that code formatting exists on Stackoverflow: [no need for screenshots of text](/help/how-to-ask), just copy-paste the actual ASCII and put it in your post with code fences.

Comment: I completely forgot about code formatting, thanks for reminding me @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: This works fine for me:
https://playcode.io/886906/ So try that code directly without database, if it works fine, then it must be how data saved in the database, in which case either try @BillKarwin suggestion or trim in javascript: `ok.Username.trim()` and `ok.Password.trim()`

Comment: Thank you so much @BillKarwin. SELECT Username, HEX(Password) AS Password FROM rbinfo worked like a charm. Once again thank you!

Comment: I hope you're considering the security of your setup - it is against standard practice to store a list of plaintext passwords, especially if code is actively outputting that list somewhere.